# Xamarin Native Binding - Kotlin constructor

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-binding, xamarin-native

I am have added Native Binding for Android in Xamarin.  But, Class constructor is added with one more new parameter "DefaultConstructorMarker _constructor_marker".

I have no clue to create this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the `Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib` package when you created the kotlin binding library?

There was a existed [similar issue](https://github.com/xamarin/java.interop/issues/694) on the github, according to the link, the problem has been fixed  in Xamarin.Android SDK version and Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 Preview 3, so you can try to update the xamarin.android verison in your project by upgrading the visual studio.

For more information, you can check the official document about [binding a kotlin library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-kotlin-library/walkthrough) and the issue I mentioned above.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac (Professional).  Xamarin.Android SDK 12.2.

Comment: You can try to upgrade the visual studio. @SivagnanamSubramani